# dotnet build access to path is denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, .net-core

I've created a jenkins server, and I am trying to build a .net core 2.0.0 project on the server. I've been able to successfully pull from source control and store source files in the workspace. However, I'm running into an issue with running the dotnet build command. This is what I'm getting.

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4116,5):
>   error MSB3021: Unable to copy file
>   "obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/ubuntu.16.04-x64/Musify.pdb" to
>   "bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/ubuntu.16.04-x64/Musify.pdb". Access to the
>   path is denied. [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Musify/Musify.csproj]

now, I've given read write and execute permissions to every file and directory in /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/, and I've given read write and execute to every file and directory in my workspace (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Musify). I also believe my jenkins user is part of the sudo group.

The weird thing I am experiencing, is that I am able to, as root, run dotnet build in my workspace directory (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Musify), and the project builds. I cannot however, get the same results under the jenkins user (who should be part of the sudo group). My question is, how can I verify that Jenkins is using the jenkins system user, and that this user has the correct permissions to run this command. I am hosting jenkins on an ubuntu 16.04 x64 server.

UPDATE:
[image: Adding this to show ps -ef | grep jenkins]

Comment: You just need to give full permission and the error should be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

At the command line on your jenkins host run

`ps -ef | grep jenkins`

the first column will give you the USERID and it should be, as you say,  jenkins

Then if you can login as jenkins to the host where the jenkins server is running run the following ....

`groups`

this will list out the groups that jenkins is a part of

Comment: I'm not too sure what I'm looking at for output

Comment: Add the output to the question. I'll take a look.

Comment: Added it to the op

Comment: From that output the Jenkins server is running using the jenkins account.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fix the `dotnet build` issue take following actions:

1. Set `DOTNET_CLI_HOME` environment variable on the docker to a common
   path like `/tmp` on the container. This path is used by the `dotnet`
   to create necessary files to build the project. Check
   [Dotnet build permission denied in Docker container running Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556623/dotnet-build-permission-denied-in-docker-container-running-jenkins)
2. Use `-o` or another accessible path to create the artifacts in the desired directory. e.g. `dotnet build -o /tmp/dotnet/build/
   microsoftisnotthatbad.sln`

Re the jenkins user problem, run `whoami` in the container. If you get `whoami: cannot find name for user ID blahblah` it means **the user is not found in the `passwd` file**. There are 2 answers under [Docker Plugin for Jenkins Pipeline - No user exists for uid 1005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404473/docker-plugin-for-jenkins-pipeline-no-user-exists-for-uid-1005/57175535#57175535), if item 1 did not work, try the second:

1. Mount the host `passwd` to the container.
2. If the jenkins user is logged using an identity provider like `LDAP` on the Jenkins server or the slave server your job is using, the `passwd` file of the host will not have the jenkins user. Check the other answer on that post.