# Dotnet build permission denied in Docker container running Jenkins

Tags: .net, docker, jenkins, asp.net-core, build

I am trying to build a .NET application using Jenkins. The Jenkins instance is running in a Docker container.

My Jenkinsfile is as follows:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk'
      registryUrl 'https://index.docker.io/v1/'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'dotnet build MyApplication/Application.csproj -c Release -o /app'
      }
    }
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'dotnet test MyApplication/Application.csproj -c Release -r /results'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I attempt the build I am seeing the following error in the Jenkins build output:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/.dotnet' is denied. ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.EnvironmentAbstractions.DirectoryWrapper.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.FileSentinel.Create()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.DotnetFirstTimeUseConfigurer.Configure()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ConfigureDotNetForFirstTimeUse(INuGetCacheSentinel nugetCacheSentinel, IFirstTimeUseNoticeSentinel firstTimeUseNoticeSentinel, IAspNetCertificateSentinel aspNetCertificateSentinel, IFileSentinel toolPathSentinel, Boolean hasSuperUserAccess, DotnetFirstRunConfiguration dotnetFirstRunConfiguration, IEnvironmentProvider environmentProvider)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

It appears that the '.dotnet' folder is protected in the Docker container. Is there a way of getting read/write permission on this, or a way of changing it's location? I can't seem to find the folder when I bash into the container.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue appeared to be linked to trying to write data to the top level of the Docker container ('/').

Adding the following to the Jenkinsfile ensures that the home directory is set and the .dotnet folder can be created in a location with correct permissions.

```
environment {
   HOME = '/tmp'
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem, but is not a good idea if other scripts rely on home to be somewhere else, or if there is a bootstrapping issue where you have the `USER` set in the Dockerfile, something is set in `~/.blah` and suddenly `HOME` is set to a different location `/tmp`.

Answer (score 21):

You can set the `HOME` environment variable as @colmulhall suggested, but then you will set the docker container home directory to `/tmp`.

To do it in `"dotnet"` way set the environment variable `DOTNET_CLI_HOME`:

```
environment {
    DOTNET_CLI_HOME = "/tmp/DOTNET_CLI_HOME"
}
```

Or before calling `dotnet` run:

```
export DOTNET_CLI_HOME="/tmp/DOTNET_CLI_HOME"
```

### Update

A sample Jenkins pipeline code taken from https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/

Look how `DOTNET_CLI_HOME` is defined in the `environment` section:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label '!windows'
    }

    environment {
        DISABLE_AUTH = 'true'
        DB_ENGINE    = 'sqlite'
        DOTNET_CLI_HOME = "/tmp/DOTNET_CLI_HOME"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo "Database engine is ${DB_ENGINE}"
                echo "DISABLE_AUTH is ${DISABLE_AUTH}"
                sh 'printenv'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are many ways to achieve this. If you are using docker, maybe a better way is defining the environment variable `DOTNET_CLI_HOME` in the docker image.

Comment: Where do I need to write this code  `environment {.. `

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya if you are using Jenkins look at this to fin out how you can define an environment variable in a jenkins pipeline stage: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/

Comment: This might seem 'cleaner', but some tools (`dotnet tools`) line f.ex SonarQube can blowup if only `DOTNET_CLI_HOME` is set but `HOME` isn't

Answer (score 3):

### Custom Docker Image, minimal changes to Jenkinsfile

This option is good if you have the following conditions.

1. You have multiple Jenkinsfile projects all using the same docker image.
2. You have custom Nuget package source.

If you are using a custom docker image, based off the dotnet sdk docker image. You can create a Docker file with the following.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
WORKDIR /

# Setup default nuget.config, useful for custom nuget servers/sources
# Set Project-specific NuGet.Config files located in any folder from the solution folder up to the drive root. These allow control over settings as they apply to a project or a group of projects.
COPY nuget.config .

# Set the Environment Variable for the DOTNET CLI HOME PATH
ARG dotnet_cli_home_arg=/tmp/
ENV DOTNET_CLI_HOME=$dotnet_cli_home_arg
```

Create your image in the same directory as your docker file.

```
docker build -t jenkins-dotnet:latest .
```

Set your tag for the server you want to push to.

```
docker tag jenkins-dotnet:latest some.docker.registry/jenkins-dotnet
```

Push your **jenkins-dotnet** image to

```
docker push some.docker.registry/jenkins-dotnet
```

Then your **Jenkinsfile** for all of the projects could be something as follows.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'some.docker.registry/jenkins-dotnet'
      registryUrl 'https://some.docker.registry'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'dotnet build MyApplication/Application.csproj -c Release -o /app'
      }
    }
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'dotnet test MyApplication/Application.csproj -c Release -r /results'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a User. e.g:

```
RUN useradd -m jenkinsbuild
```

to your Dockerfile before calling any `dotnet` call, fixes the issue.

Now `$HOME` is set and `dotnet` does not use the root-folder `/`