# Unable to run dotnet test in docker container when run as non root

Tags: .net, docker, containers, root, .net-5

**Problem:**
Running `dotnet test` in container as non root user fails.

**Details:**

`dotnet test` runs successfully using the following docker file and docker command on running as root user.

Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build    
WORKDIR /app
# run the tests
COPY [".", "."]
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","test"]
```

Docker build command:

```
docker build -t test:v1 .
```

Docker run command:

```
docker run test:v1
```

On contrary, if I run `dotnet test` as non root user using the following docker file and above docker build and run command then it fails.

Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build

RUN mkdir -p /app/DOTNET_CLI_HOME
ENV DOTNET_CLI_HOME="/app/DOTNET_CLI_HOME"
RUN adduser --disabled-password --system --uid 1000 --home /app --gecos "" dotnetuser && chown -R dotnetuser /app

USER dotnetuser

WORKDIR /app

# run the component tests
COPY [".", "."]
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","test"]
```

Description of above docker file:

`ENV DOTNET_CLI_HOME="/app/DOTNET_CLI_HOME"` is added to mitigate `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` error. Details can be seen in this link :
[Dotnet build permission denied in Docker container running Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556623/dotnet-build-permission-denied-in-docker-container-running-jenkins)

But despite of that I get the error on running the container with above Docker file. Logs:

> Determining projects to restore...
> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.102/NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Access to
> the path '/app/obj/808903f8-54b1-4814-9c09-345ae588c134.tmp' is
> denied. [/app/simpleapi-test.csproj]
> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.102/NuGet.targets(131,5): error :
> Permission denied [/app/simpleapi-test.csproj]

I want to run dotnet test in a container as non-root user.
It would be great if someone could help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a non-root user in your builds directly instead of creating in the Dockerfile. You just have to add an environment variable like this during build command.
`-e PUID=1000 -e PGID=1000`

So your Dockerfile would be:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build

RUN mkdir -p /app/DOTNET_CLI_HOME
ENV DOTNET_CLI_HOME="/app/DOTNET_CLI_HOME"

USER dotnetuser

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","test"]
```

Also, it's adviced not to copy everything inside your docker image, you can either selectively copy the required files or do a  `COPY . .` and add unwanted files in a **.dockerignore** file.

So, finally, your docker build will be:

```
docker build -e PUID=1000 -e PGID=1000  -t test:v1 .
```

Sorry I haven't worked with dotnet so cannot help you with a production grade image, but if you are looking to create a non-root docker image, this is how it's done. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I resolved it using the below answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67714717/2356919

Answer (score 0):

The order of instructions in Docker file was wrong. After I corrected it using the below docker file, everything worked as expected.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
RUN mkdir -p /app/DOTNET_CLI_HOME

COPY [".", "/app"]

ENV DOTNET_CLI_HOME="/app/DOTNET_CLI_HOME"

RUN adduser --disabled-password --system --uid 1000 --home /app --gecos "" dotnetuser && chown -R dotnetuser /app

USER dotnetuser

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","test"]
```